# Apache Reverse Proxy get 404 error

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, http-status-code-404

I set up an apache reverse Proxy Server. In general it works and does what it should.
But now i want it to Proxy a request to an external URL. While a wget on the URL works the Proxy keeps giving me a 404.

The ssl.conf snip:

```
<VirtualHost 10.*.*.*:7006>
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    ServerName ***********
```

[...]

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://10.*.*.*:7002/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://10.*.*.*:7002/

    #New
            ProxyPass /test https://correct.url
            ProxyPassReverse /test https://correct.url
```

The wget command works correct:

`wget https://correct.url
--2018-02-19 17:43:59--  https://correct.url
Resolving correct.url... 10.*.*.*
Connecting to correct.url|10.*.*.*|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.`

I tried to set the ProxyPreserveHost to Off but that had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the ProxyPass /test above the ProxyPass /
The directives are evaluated in order with first-match, so in your configuration every request to /test is served by the proxy defined for /.